# Select Homepage of your choice in php

Tags: php

I have video website. I hae two options to choose from for the homepage. e.g. 
SEt Homepage: [Index1](http://abc)/[Index2](http://abc2). The user will select out of these two and it will be his index page till the Session or Cookie expires.
It would be like www.mysite.com(with any option selected. The url will not show the selected option for the homepage).
I am not able to figure out any solution yet.

Comment: May be u have to store the specific users index page in database and redirect to that

Comment: have you tried from your self?

Comment: i tried it myself.. finally something got struck to my mind.. and i achieved the result.

Answer (score 1):

what i have done is passed the name of the page in the anchor tag, captured it in the session and checked if the session is not empty execute the particaular query..

```
<?php 
if(!empty($_SESSION['homepage'])){ 
$index = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['homepage']); } if($index=='popular'){ $SQL= "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE condition1";}
if($index=='newest'){ $SQL= "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE condition2"; }
?>
```

Comment: STOP USING `mysql_` LIBRARY, IT IS DEPRECATED!

Comment: use `PDO`, or `mysqli_`

Answer (score 0):

try something like this in your index.php file

```
if(check your session or cookie){
   require_once("index1.php");
}else{
   require_once("index2.php");
}
```